# In the language Pyret, what does 'shadow' do?

Tags: programming-languages, pyret

With Pyret, I can't find any documentation on `shadow` does.  Here's the block of code which I came across this:

```
fun parse(s :: S.S-Exp) -> ArithC:
  cases (S.S-Exp) s:
    | s-num(n) => numC(n)
    | s-list(shadow s) =>
      cases (List) s:
        | empty => raise("parse: unexpected empty list")
        | link(op, args) =>
          argL = L.index(args, 0)
          argR = L.index(args, 1)
          if op.s == "+":
            plusC(parse(argL), parse(argR))
          else if op.s == "*":
            multC(parse(argL), parse(argR))
          end
      end
    | else =>
      raise("parse: not number or list")
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language but shadowing usually refers to having a new variable with the same name as one in a visible outer scope. It can be confusing. Perhaps 'shadow' is a keyword that you use to allow shadowing? If you remove it, does the compiler complain about redefining 's'?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Yes!!! That's it, without the 'shadow' the compiler complain about re-declaring `s`.  The shadow I guess, means 'in-this-block-this-is-what-s-referes-to'.  If you convert your comment to answer I'll vote it and mark it correct.

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the language but shadowing usually refers to having a new variable with the same name as one in a visible outer scope. It can be confusing. Perhaps 'shadow' is a keyword that you use to allow shadowing? If you remove it, does the compiler complain about redefining 's'?

Comment: The language was created to mimic the form of python from the folks at DrRacket, but to includes a number of additions to allow for more conducive teaching of programming language fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for shadowing in Pyret, that can be found [here](http://www.pyret.org/docs/latest/Bindings.html#%28part._.Shadowing%29):

> Pyret does not permit a program to implicitly bind the same name
>   multiple times in the same scope, as this can be confusing or
>   ambiguous: which name was meant?
>
> ```
>   ans = 3 + 4
>
>   ans = true # did you mean to use a different name here?
>   ans # which one was meant?
> ```
>
> Pyret will signal an error on the second
>   binding of ans above, saying that it shadows the earlier definition.
>   The same rule applies to names defined in nested scopes, like
>   functions. This program is disallowed by the shadowing rule, as well:
>
> ```
>   ans = 3 + 4
>
>   fun oops(x):
>     ans = x * 2  # Shadows the outer ans
>     ans
>   end
>
>   fun another-oops(ans): # Also shadows the outer ans
>     if ans: 3 else: 4 end
>   end
> ```
>
> The general rule for shadowing is to look "upward and leftward", i.e.
>   looking outward from the current scope to any enclosing scopes, to see
>   if there are any existing bindings of the same name.
>
> But sometimes, redefining the same name makes the most sense. In this
>   case, a program can explicitly specify that it means to hide the outer
>   definition, using the shadow keyword:
>
> ```
>   ans = 3 + 4
>   fun oops(x):
>     shadow ans = x * 2 # <-------------------------+
>     ans    # uses the ans defined the line above --+
>   end
>   fun another-oops(shadow ans):
>     if ans: 3 else: 3 end # uses the function's parameter
>   end
> ```